# Best way to use methods from parent directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I interested in advice, which way of using parent directive methods in its child directive.
**Method one:** Pas it as a scope parameter in html where you init child directive.
**Method two:** Make parent directive required and get access to parent controller. egz:

```
module.directive('widget', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '?^^widgetContainer', <-- here
            scope: {
                widgetItem: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elems, attrs, controller) {

                        controller.rejectWidgetAdd(scope.widgetItem);
                    controller.removeWidget(scope.widgetItem);  
            },
            templateUrl: 'plugins/workspace/app/widget/view.html'
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: I prefer method one since you could use both directives standalone. But I think it depends on various aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Using the require approach (**method two** above) creates a kind of "strong reference" between child directive and parent directive. The [official guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) explaining this directive-property uses a tab-bar and tabs as example. Following that I would suggest using the require method when the child directive may not be used reasonable on its own. Separating these two logical objects into own directives is done mainly for better readability and separation of concerns.

Passing the controller into the directive via an attribute may be considered a "weak reference" or usage of an interface in Java. The child directive does not force a specific parent implementation, although expecting some common methods that are used (otherwise errors will appear on runtime). It is thereby possible to easily exchange the "parent" controller with another implementation. Binding would happen with `&`. The angularJS guide uses an example where the closing method of a dialog is passed into the dialog's scope via reference.
Following that, your "**method one**" should be used whenever the child directive can be reasonably used as stand-alone. The method it accesses from it's "parent" is used in an API fashion and not a central logical ingredient. For example a directive displaying a list of items, the sorting/ordering function may be passed in as attribute.